# IntBuffer to image file in Android using PNGj

Tags: android, bitmap, png

I have an OpenGL buffer in IntBuffer that contains all the pixels of rendered image.

```
IntBuffer ib = IntBuffer.allocate(mWidth * mHeight);
mGL.glReadPixels(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ib);
```

I have more than 5000x5000 size image and when i try to allocate its buffer (and save it as bitmap using following code), it throws OutOfMemory Error. I have tried larg H

```
mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWidth, mHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
mBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(IntBuffer.wrap(iat));
```

I would like to do this process in chunks. After too much research i found PNGj library do what i exactly want.

But I am not able to find any help of converting IntBuffer to Image data and store it in file in PNGj.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

[PNGJ](https://github.com/leonbloy/pngj/) is a low level encoding library, it writes and reads image lines in a raw format. The format is explained in the [docs](https://github.com/leonbloy/pngj/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-readwrite-the-pixels-values).
In the case of ARGB (8 bits), you only need to allocate an array of bytes (or ints) with width x 4 values, and copy the values from your `IntBuffer`. In the [Snippets](https://github.com/leonbloy/pngj/wiki/Snippets) page there is an example using a `BufferedImage` (`TYPE_INT_ARGB`), very similar to your scenario.